# Options to use multithreading to process a group of database records?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services

I have a database table that contains some records to be processed. The table has a flag column that represents the following status values. 1 - ready to be processed, 2- successfully processed, 3- processing failed.

The .net code (repeating process - console/service) will grab a list of records that are ready to be processed, and loop through them and attempt to process them (Not very lengthy), update status based on success or failure.

To have better performance, I want to enable multithreading for this process. I'm thinking to spawn say 6 threads, each threads grabbing a subset.

Obviously I want to avoid having different threads process the same records. I dont want to have a "Being processed" flag in the database to handle the case where the thread crashes leaving the record hanging.

The only way I see doing this is to grab the complete list of available records and assigning a group (maybe ids) to each thread. If an individual thread fails, its unprocessed records will be picked up next time the process runs.

Is there any other alternatives to dividing the groups prior to assigning them to threads?

Comment: Do you have any identity column in your table?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using your database as a queue. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database-as-IPC

Comment: Threads, and processes, die unexpectedly and mostly at the worst time.  Tying a DB ID to a thread ID / thread number is not a good idea.

Comment: @Oded: I agree that a transactional queue is a better idea, but the anti-pattern you link to says using the DB is an anti-pattern when e.g. sockets could be used.  Right idea, not a perfect reference though.

Comment: @EricJ. - Aye. Though good references are difficult to come by. By all means, if you have a better one...

Comment: @Oded, the wikipedia link nor the article posted there dont provide a REAL alternative for db as queue. Its very simple to write "use sockets instead", but what does that even mean? How are You supposed to handle transactions (either success or failure/retry), just for example, with sockets? The fact that people dont queue/process items correctly within the db (As the link there explains) doesnt mean the idea itself is anti pattern, especially when in 99% of the cases you want the processed items to remain there for archiving.

Comment: @YavgenyP: Indeed, if I recall correctly, MSMQ in transactional mode uses SQL server as the persistence mechanism :-)

Comment: I agree database queuing is not always ideal. But one thing I have not mentioned here is that the record goes through many stages (handled by different processes) before it is marked as success or failure, for eg, initialized, moved to status A, B, and then success or failure. Not sure if queue is still good for those scenarios. I read somewhere when workflows like that are invovled, db is better.

Comment: Have a look at Windows Workflow Foundation if there is still room to change your architecture.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx

Comment: @Eric, yes, I have room to change architecture as we are still in the design stage. Have you used WWF for anything similar? any samples or articles that you have for similar cases?. I will do research as well, but if you have something, that will be great.

Comment: @AlexJ: I have not, but some friends have used it successfully.  If you want to go down that road, I suggest a small pilot project to get familiar and ensure it meets your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward way to implement this requirement is to use the Task Parallel Library's

[Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) (or [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for)).

Allow it to manage individual worker threads.

From experience, I would recommend the following:

- Have an additional status "Processing"
- Have a column in the database that indicates when a record was picked up for processing and a cleanup task / process that runs periodically looking for records that have been "Processing" for far too long (reset the status to "ready for processing).
- Even though you don't want it, "being processed" will be essential to crash recovery scenarios (unless you can tolerate the same record being processed twice).

**Alternatively**

Consider using a transactional queue (MSMQ or Rabbit MQ come to mind).  They are optimized for this very problem.

That would be my clear choice, having done both at massive scale.

**Optimizing**

If it takes a non-trivial amount of time to retrieve data from the database, you can consider a Producer/Consumer pattern, which is quite straightforward to implement with a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).  That pattern allows one thread (producer) to populate a queue with DB records to be processed, and multiple other threads (consumers) to process items off of that queue.

**A New Alternative**

Given that several processing steps touch the record before it is considered complete, have a look at [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx) as a possible alternative.

Comment: What do you mean by "being processed" is required for crash recovery. It is really not, if the record status was not updated to either success or failure, it will be processed again. Only after it is set to success or failure, it is deemed as processed. Until then you can play it again and again. I do not want to have yet another process looking to reset "being processed" flag which may not be entirely accurate and I also cannot afford the delay at times for that process to reset the flag to be processed again.

Comment: I also agree MSMQ is a good alternative. But one thing I have not mentioned here is that the record goes through many stages (handled by different processes) before it is marked as success or failure, for eg, initialized, moved to status A, B, and then success or failure. Not sure if queue is still good for those scenarios. I read somewhere when workflows like that are invovled, db is better.

Comment: @AlexJ: "Only after it is set to success or failure, it is deemed as processed" means that you don't need the extra status.  Many systems cannot allow partially processed records to just be re-processed without some rollback logic.  Since yours can tolerate that, you are good to go in that regard.  I would just go with Parallel.ForEach() then, and introduce a BlockingQueue if and only if you spend significant time getting records from the DB before they can be processed.

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations. I think I may still use a blocking queue as I can bring all the "ready ones" into the queue one time and have Parallel.ForEach process from the blockingCollection. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Theres one thing maybe you'd want to add to Eric's suggestion: separating within the db your processed items and those waiting to be processed. In the long run (the link from wikipedias article Oded posted desribes this as well), such queue tables tend to get huge, unless you delete / move your processed items, and it will eventually slow down the entire processing just because of the slow selection.

Comment: Correct. I will have to use SQL server partitioning to "archive" the data for the table as it grows. I cannot "delete" due to audit trail, reporting etc.

Comment: I almost -1 for the inclusion of the Workflow link as an "Alternative". While interesting, it really is not related (I *use* these beasts).

Comment: I am curious to see how Workflow can do this too. I did some researching but didn't quite understand how to use it for the same. Total newbie to that. Still looking..

Comment: @pst: He seems to have multiple processing stages that need to happen sequentially.  How is Workflow not related?  Not arguing with you, but rather curious to understand why you feel that way.

Answer (score 2):

I remember doing something like what you described...A thread checks from time to time if there is something new in database that needs to be processed. It will load only the new ids, so if at time x last id read is 1000, at x+1 will read from id 1001.

Everything it reads goes into a thread safe Queue. When items are added to this queue, you notify the working threads (maybe use autoreset events, or spawn threads here). each thread will read from this thread safe queue one item at a time, until the queue is emptied.

You should not assign before the work foreach thread (unless you know that foreach file the process takes the same amount of time). if a thread finishes the work, then it should take the load from the other ones left. using this thread safe queue, you make sure of this.

Comment: If you use an in-memory queue, you cannot recover from crash scenarios unless it is acceptable to process the same record multiple times.

Comment: indeed, but if he cannot change those 3 states?

Comment: Ah, but he can.  He just said he doesn't want to because of thread crash recovery, but in fact he needs to, to enable recovery (assuming replays of records are not permissible).

Comment: Ok. I assumed that another application is inserting those values and he has to take them for granted. Then it's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that does not rely/use an additional database column (but see #4) or mandate an in-process queue. The *premise this approach is to "shard" records across workers* based on some consistent value, much like a distributed cache.

Here are my assumptions:

1. Re-processing does not cause unwanted side-effects; at most some work "is wasted".
2. The number of threads is fixed upon start-up. This is not a requirement, but it does simplify the implementation and allows me to skip transitory details in the simple description below.
3. There is only one "worker process" (but see #1) controlling the "worker threads". This simplifies dealing with how the records are split between workers.
4. There is some [immutable] "ID" column which is "well distributed". This is required so search worker gets about the same amount of work.
5. Work can be done "out of order" as long as it is "eventually done". Also, workers might not always run "at 100%" due to each one effectively working on a different queue.

Assign each thread a unique `bucket` value from `[0, thread_count)`. If a thread dies/is restarted it will take the same bucket as that which it vacated.

Then, each time a thread needs a new record is needed it will fetch from the database:

```
SELECT *
FROM record
WHERE state = 'unprocessed'
AND (id % $thread_count) = $bucket
ORDER BY date
```

There could of course be other assumptions made about reading the "this threads tasks" in batch and storing them locally. A local queue, however, would be *per thread* (and thus re-loaded upon a new thread startup) and thus it would only deal with records associated for the given `bucket`.

When the thread is finished processing a record should mark the record as processed using the appropriate isolation level and/or optimistic concurrency and proceed to the next record.

Comment: Why manage the threads yourself?  The TPL is so good at that... Plus, this requires multiple round-trips to the database where otherwise one will do.

Comment: @EricJ. I was trying to avoid specifying the implementation of the threads. The idea of this approach is to "shard" records across worker threads based on some consistent value, much like a distributed cache.

Comment: But your specifying that the implementation will *not* be Parallel.For(Each), since both manage the thread lifecycle automatically and would not alloy your second assumption to hold.

Comment: @EricJ. No. That is a fallacious argument. I outlined some assumptions. It is up to the implementation to work within the given constraints or to re-define/alter them.

Comment: Last word on this... your second assumption makes it impossible to use Parallel.For(Each), and indeed sacrifices the ability to leverage a powerful and simple tool designed specifically for this class of problem.  I'll leave it at that :-)